# What does display: -webkit-box do, and what browsers support it?

Tags: css, display

I ran into a situation where using the `display: -webkit-box;` fixes an issue for me when no other display property did.

I wonder if I can use it and if it's supported for all browsers.

Comment: I got here by searching for this property due to a project where I used -webkit-box back in around 2012 or something, by that time, a lot of CSS3 and HTML5 stuff was basically experimental, and a lot of features used browser prefixes such was "webkit" or "moz" due to browsers having slightly different implementations.

I believe this is equivalent to display: flex (or has evolved into it), but I realized I don't need to confirm it for my project, whatever the case is, I don't think this should be used in modern code.

Comment: For some reason it's different from the other display properties. In my case I solved my problem using another medthos. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `display: -webkit-box` on an element to be able to use `line-clamp` or `-webkit-line-clamp` with it. Those two properties set the maximum number of lines of text a box can be. With `text-overflow: ellipsis`, the text will end with an ellipsis if truncated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

Answer (score 4):

I believe `display: -webkit-box;` is an old flexbox syntax and is no longer used.

This is a great website if you ever have questions on browser support: [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/?search=webkit-box)

The link shows the results for `display: -webkit-box;`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the website, I think the result shown is for `-webkit-box-reflect` for some reason there is so little information on the internet about this property, even on MDN

Comment: I don't want to risk it so I just used another way to solve my problem

Comment: what was the way? @AWIXOR